# Bochner integrals with values in a Hilbert $A$-module

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, integration, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm wondering whether there exists a generalisation of Bochner integration with values in a Hilbert $A$-module $M$, where $A$ is a general $C^*$-algebra rather than $\mathbb{C}$ (and whether there are notes out there on this). When $A=\mathbb{C}$, one knows that if $(S,\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:S\rightarrow H$ is a Bochner-integrable function with values in $H$, then the identity

$$\langle x,\,\int_S f(s)\,d\mu(s)\rangle = \int_S\langle x,\, f(s)\rangle\,d\mu(s),$$

is satisfied for all $x\in H$.

Does there exist an integration theory for more general $A$ that still has this property? That is, if $(S,\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:S\rightarrow M$ is an integrable function in the sense of this theory, then is it true that

$$\langle x,\,\int_S f(s)\,d\mu(s)\rangle = \int_S\langle x,\, f(s)\rangle\,d\mu(s),$$

for all $x\in M$?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the second statement? Since the $A$-module structure does not appear in the statement, it seems obviously true.

Comment: But the inner product in the second equality takes values in $A$, right?

Comment: The usual Bochner integral has the property that it commutes with every continuous linear map.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know whether the direct analogue of the usual Bochner integral makes sense for Hilbert module-valued functions. I can see that uniqueness is guaranteed once existence is proved. Perhaps it would be more accurate to refer to this as a Gelfand-Pettis integral rather than a Bochner integral...

Comment: Bochner integrals exist for functions with values in any locally convex space, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3207.pdf

Comment: Theorem C.12 in Raeburn-Williams's book "Morita equivalence and continuous-trace $C^*$-algebras" might be relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks Corbennick and t.c. for the nice references. Now I'm reasonably convinced that Bochner integration theory gives the property in the second equality. I just have to make sense of some integrals with values in a (non-separable) C*-algebra...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555677/checking-a-separability-condition-for-bochner-measurability